# Is there an option to connect multiple bot accounts to a one discord.js code?

Tags: discord.js

I'm creating a mass of bots that would ping me just to beat world record in pings so I decided to create 20 bots but now I'm wondering if it's possible to connect one code to multiple bot accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere in your code there should be

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

Instead make an array

```
const clients = [ new Discord.Client(), new Discord.Client(), new Discord.Client()];
```

And everywhere you used your client variable make a loop for every client in the array instead.

Comment: Please note that you don't necessarily **need** an array to accomplish this, as you can just simply create new `Discord.Client` instances anywhere and it'll work just fine--it all depends on your case.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're describing, to my knowledge isn't possible but there is another way. Just make every one of the bots have the same prefix and command so when you run `!ping` for example, all the bots would respond. So just copy and paste all the same code into each bot.

Comment: You can certainly have multiple Discord.js `Client` instances running under the same code, as they are self-contained instances and not globally-stated.